# Manage space in legend print composer QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend

I am struggling to figure out how to manage space in the legend.

I have extra space between some items in my legend, which I would like to remove:

[image]

How can I manage these spaces?

I built my legend by adding an extra group layer with the legend items in it stored in 3 different layers (Infrastructure, BAL and Radians).

Every time I used a rule based classification, and it doesn't show any issues for the BAL and Radians groups.

But it doesn't work as I'd like in Infrastructure group. There is extra space between the two NRO and Infra layers.

How can I remove this extra space?

EDIT : here is a screenshot of the legend in the main QGIS window, displaying like I'd like in the print composer.

[image]

Comment: What does the "Legend items" look like from the legends item properties. If you take a screenshot of it.

Comment: Same trouble here - it looks like composer treated every (or not simple) symbol as square or expand it into square bounds and add some extra spacing... I also didn't found any solution (not counting some obvious like create only square-composed icons on map).

Comment: could you create two legends and change the spacing on just one?

Comment: Vesanto I edited and added a screenshot of the legend in the main QGIS window.

Comment: iant, I could make different legends indeed and position them manually, but I'm preparing a template for other users who are not familiar with QGIS so I have to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: Very strange, will probably need the QML file. You could just paste the contents of the QML file into Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Yes, you can find it here http://pastebin.com/WFpWE9Hq

Comment: I think this is a bug in QGIS to do with how custom symbologies are represented in the legend. So with the "Infra existante" symbol, it has a size of 30, but is rotated 90 degrees, the height in the legend is still set to 30, whereas it should impact the width due to the rotation. I would post this to the bug tracker with the QML file and the images: https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues/new

Comment: Very well, thank you for your input and your time, and I'll look forward for a future correction.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust spacing using the "Spacing" part of the Legend Item Properties:

Does adjusting any of these help?

[image]

Comment: It does help, but it modifies everything and does not correct the disproportions between the problematic items.