# QGIS spacing of individual labels

Tags: qgis, legend

I'd like to increase the space between the symbol and the text for only one item in my legend; I can only seem to increases for all the items.

Specifically, I want to combine the two screen shots such that the labels for all items except GNSS = Figure 1 (left) and the GNSS label = Figure 2 (right). 
Similar to [Manage space in legend print composer QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231062/manage-space-in-legend-print-composer-qgis) but would like to avoid using two legends.

<kbd>[image: Figure 1]
Figure 1</kbd>

<kbd>[image: Figure 2]
Figure 2</kbd>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how did you add the rectangle into your legend, but it looks like it is a graphic rectangle. Now to control the space for only one item in the legend, you can **double-click** the text in the legend (GNSS) and click on the space button on the keyboard to shift the text by the number of spaces you like.

The result will be something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not sure what a 'graphic rectangle' is, the symbol is just two simple markers offset from one another. Unfortunately, I can't select an individual item after clicking the legend; I can only select the whole leged and then edit the properties.

Comment: @bbuzz31 you need to select the text in legend item under the Auto update. Double click on the text and you can shift text but space button.

Comment: ah! perfect thank you, i feel stupid

Comment: @bbuzz31 you are welcome. I am glad it solved the problem :)